# Why does using the shorthand "if" syntax does not evaluate when searching for a sub-string using "include?"

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator

I attempted to use the shorthand to get a response based on the existance of a sub-string, instead of the expected string response, it evaluated to "false." In my second simpler example the expect string was printed.

**#fails**

```
puts "test".include? "s" ? "yep" : "nope"
```

**#success**

```
puts 1>2 ? "1 is greater than 2" : "1 is not greater than 2"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) problem.

## Solution

You need :

```
puts "test".include?("s") ? "yep" : "nope"
#=> yep
```

## Why?

Method call without parenthesis is somewhere between `defined?` and `or` in the precedence table, so it is lower than the ternary operator. It means that

```
puts "test".include? "s" ? "yep" : "nope"
```

is parsed as

```
puts "test".include?("s" ? "yep" : "nope")
```

which is

```
puts "test".include?("yep")
```

which is

```
false
```

## Warning

```
"s" ? "yep" : "nope"
```

displays a warning :

```
warning: string literal in condition
```

because ternary operator expects a boolean, and a String is always truthy.

## 1 > 2

The reason this works

```
puts 1>2 ? "1 is greater than 2" : "1 is not greater than 2"
```

is that the ternary operator has a higher precedence than puts :

```
puts ( 1>2 ? "1 is greater than 2" : "1 is not greater than 2" )
```

It is evaluated as :

```
puts ( "1 is not greater than 2" )
```

## One last tip

When you have precedence problem, using `puts` without parenthesis might just make the problem worse. You can fire up IRB and see what the result is directly.

Here's an example :

```
# in a script :
puts [1,2,3].map do |i|
  i * 2
end
#=> #<Enumerator:0x0000000214d708>
```

With IRB :

```
[1,2,3].map do |i|
  i * 2
end
# => [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: This answer is becoming an epic. Love it.

Comment: Binding strength is the key here. Precedence is a more general term that means the same thing.

Comment: @tadman : interesting, thanks. I just googled "Binding strength Ruby", and mostly found your answers on SO. Do you have any reference?

Comment: @EricDuminil The very first link here on precedence establishes what's going on. Binding strength is another way of conceptualizing what's happening.

Comment: Maybe I've invented the term and convinced myself it was a thing, or possibly it's some term from chemistry I'm applying to programming. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ruby is unable to parse this as you're expecting without a little help. It thinks you're doing

```
puts "test".include?("s" ? "yep" : "nope")
```

You need to either use the (optional) parens around the argument

```
puts "test".include?("s") ? "yep" : "nope"
```

or force the test expression to be interpreted as a whole:

```
puts ("test".include?"s") ? "yep" : "nope"
```

Comment: Why would get downvoted? I don't understand. Downvoters : please leave a comment.

Comment: Not sure why but the lack of capital letters might drive people into a frothing down-voting rage.

Comment: Also, you're missing an `?` in your first snippet.